# Trigger a downstream pipeline only if upstream passes: Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am new to Azure devops. I have two pipelines:

```
A-> Runs unit tests
B-> Performs deployment onto the server.
```

The current setup is I have configured **B to be triggered upon build completion of A.**

[image]

However, I assume that this will trigger B despite if A passes/fails/partially succeeds.

I would want the pipeline B to run only if pipeline A is successful. How can this be achieved?

Comment: The second pipeline it's a Build pipeline or Release pipeline?

Comment: @Shayki Abramczyk....The second is a Build pipeline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Build completion" trigger will trigger the second build only if the first build finished successfuly.

Another thing, if your second build is deployment I suggest use [Relase pipline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/what-is-release-management?view=vsts).

Comment: On the contrary, if we want to trigger a the second pipeline despite of the first one failing, Is it allowed? Just being curious.

Comment: @B.TAnand I don't think it's possible with the "Build completion" trigger, but you can add a task (in the first task) that queue a new build with rest api, and the task will be executed only when the buid is failed.